# Getting this erorr You cannot define a correlation name 'news_from_date_table' more than once

Tags: magento2, query, sort, join

> When I am using above mentioned query then getting the error You
> cannot define a correlation name 'news_from_date_table' more than once

```
 $subquery = $collection->getConnection()->select()
            ->from($collection->getTable('eav_attribute'), ['attribute_id'])
            ->where('attribute_code = ?', $attributeCode);
            $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['news_from_date_table' => $collection->getTable('catalog_product_entity_datetime')],
                'e.entity_id = news_from_date_table.entity_id',
                ['news_from_date_table.*']
            )->where('news_from_date_table.attribute_id = (' . $subquery->__toString() . ')')
            ->order('news_from_date_table.value ASC');
```